# construct an asymptotic, analytic function, which outperforms $\frac{x}{\log(x)}$ but isn't quite as good as $\text{Li}(x)$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, logarithms, asymptotics

The offset logarithmic integral is defined as $$ \text{Li}(x)=\int_2^x\frac{1}{\log(t)}~dt. $$

It can be shown that $\text{Li}(x)\sim\pi(x)$ where $\pi(x)$ is the prime counting function. It can also be shown that $\frac{x}{\log(x)}\sim \pi(x).$

> Is there any practical use in number theory for constructing an asymptotic, analytic function, which outperforms $\frac{x}{\log(x)}$ but isn't quite as good as $\text{Li}(x)$?

Note: $\text {Li}(x)$ is the best possible asymptotic formula to approximate $\pi(x).$

Comment: Regarding your note: No, it isn't. It just has the advantage of being a very good approximation compared to how simple it is to describe and calculate with. $\pi(x)$ is the best possible. And there are several in-between.

Comment: I guess this works $B(x)= \int_2^x \sin(.5/\ln(t))+\sinh(.5/\ln(t))dt$ but I don't know how easy it is to calculate with

Comment: You may use $\pi(x) \approx \frac{x}{\log (x) -1}$.

Comment: Why do you want it to be analytic ? The most natural function is $\sum_{n\le x} \frac1{\log n}$. It outperforms $Li(x)$ but not $pv. \ li(x)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Speaking to the comment by user @Arthur, here is a function that supports their claim that there are "several of these candidate functions" i.e. (better than $\frac{x}{\log(x)})$ but worse than $\text{Li(x)}).$

$$ B_\kappa(x)= \int_2^x \sin\bigg(\frac{\kappa}{\log(t)}\bigg)+\sinh\bigg(\frac{\kappa}{\log(t)}\bigg)~dt.$$ for some $\kappa=0.499998$ and $x=10^6$ one gets $B(10^6)=78,626.2$ compared with $\text{Li(10^6)}=78,627.5$

And $\pi(10^6)=78,498.$

Another example without using an integral is $f(x)=\bigg(\frac{x}{\log(x)}\bigg)\exp\bigg(\frac{1}{\log(x)}\bigg).$